# Keep collection in db and do a select query over records

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I would like to provide some different services to my users; each service has an ID.

The question is, how to keep user selected services in the database?

Should I create a `services` column in my `users` table, then store service IDs there?
If yes, how to save them to be able later query database to select users with specific service selected?

Your experiences and advice are welcomed.

Comment: No. Have a separate table that relates user to service. See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create a services column in my users table

If `services` is plural than it sounds like that column would store multiple values.  That's no good.  If that's the case then this is a many-to-many relationship, which involves a linking table.  Something like this:

```
Service
----------
ID
etc.

User
----------
ID
etc.

UserService
----------
UserID (FK to User)
ServiceID (FK to Service)
```

The data being stored in the `UserService` table is essentially the *connection* between a given `User` and a given `Service`.  If there is information regarding that connection (such as the time when the `User` began using the `Service`, for example) it would also go on that table.  The main point being that the connection itself is an element being modeled, not just the `User` and the `Service`.

(Side note: In the above design there is no explicit PK on the `UserService` table like there is on the other tables.  If any given `User` can only have one connection to any given `Service` then the combination of those two FK columns can be the PK.  If there can be multiple connections, such as subscribing to a service multiple times, then you may want to introduce an explicit PK like the other tables have.)